# Floating point decimal to IEEE 754

Tags: ieee-754

How to convert m x 10^x to n x 2^y .

I want to covert 2.93 x 10^12  to IEEE-754 representation.

Comment: Check this online convertor http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/200869/46430

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options: calculate n,y explicitly:

y = ceil(log2(m*10^x)), n = (m*10^x / 2^y)

iteratively with integers only:

write integer 293 to a variable *mantissa* (and keep count of the exponent=10)

```
exp_two=0;
while (exponent>0) {
    mantissa*=10; exponent--;
    while ((mantissa & 1)==0) {
        mantissa>>=1; exp_two++;
    }
}
```

EDIT: in IEEE-754 one assumes, that `0.5<n<=1.0`. That is to be fixed (by multiplying/dividing by 2 until the condition is met and while adjusting the exponent y accordingly)

Comment: In this particular case long longs are needed (the algorithm produces 2861328125 (*2^10) == 2930000000000. Also, for a complete solution one has to ensure that the mantissa doesn't overflow -- i.e. force the >> operation and thus produce rounding errors.

Comment: There's an error in the explicit version: n is actually unknown, but for the formula we can/must assume 0.5<n<=1.0. Set it either one and adjust n and y accordingly

Comment: But what if I want to compute it without calculator (or without using this algorithm) . This was the question asked in competitive exam.

Comment: Also that formula is recursive so cannot be solved directly like this.I have done like example we have 5x10^2 then it can be written as nx2^2 since each 10 has one 2 in it and 5 do not any 2 then n becomes 125 in decimal which can be converted to binary but this also do not work for large numbers.

Comment: The recursion was noticed and fixed already. In deed the "large" numbers cannot be represented exactly in powers of two, but one has to drop least significant bits from the mantissa to keep it in the proper range (either 1+23 bits, or 1+52 bits).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
float f = 2.93E12;

unsigned int ui = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned int *>(&f);
```